# Error when customizing dates (years) on the x-axis in R using scales_x_date

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-plotly

I am trying to customise the x-axis (date) into 5 year intervals in R and it keeps returning the following error:

Error in scale_x_date(breaks = ("5 years"), labels = date_format("%Y")) :
could not find function "scale_x_date"

Comment: I think my date is not in numeric format but as a date. Could this be the source of error, if so, how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`breaks` is used to specify a vector. Specify `breaks = waiver()` allows you to use `date_breaks` to break the x-axis by `date_breaks = '5 years'`

`scale_x_date(breaks = waiver(), date_breaks = "5 years", labels = date_format("%Y"))`

@RuiBarradas pointed out that `breaks = waiver()` is not needed because it is the default setting.

Comment: `breaks = waiver()` is not needed, `date_breaks` can be used without it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks! I didn't realize it's not needed.

Comment: the issue is that R is returning an error indicating that the "scale_x_date" function is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a ggplot2 function scale_x_date() with a base R plot.